# Remove a particular part of a url string using javascript

Tags: javascript

In the following string,

```
http://blahblah.in/folder1/data?number=1&name= &customerId=123
```

I'm trying to validate the URL, that is, if any querystring parameter does not have a value, remove that parameter from the URL.

The resultant URL will be

```
http://blahblah.in/folder1/data?number=1&customerId=123
```

I tried to solve the above problem with the following code, and I know I have a mistake somewhere - can you help me find it?

```
var url = "http://blahblah.in/folder1/data?number=1&name= &customerId=123";


var tempQuestion = url.split("?");
 var temp = tempQuestion[1].split("=");
var temp2="";
var leng = temp.length;
for(i=0;i<leng;i++){


    if(temp[i].charAt(0)!="&")
        temp2 = temp2.concat(temp[i],"=");
    else 
    {
        temp2 = temp2.concat(temp[i],"");
        var x = temp2.split("&");
        temp2 = temp2.concat(x[0],"=");
    }

}

var result= tempQuestion[0].concat("?",temp2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use regular expressions as follows:

```js
    var url = 'http://blahblah.in/folder1/data?number=1&name=&other=&something=&customerId=123'
    url = url.replace(/[a-z]*=&/g,"");
    console.log(url)
    // result is: http://blahblah.in/folder1/data?number=1&customerId=123
```

Comment: You should add a case-insensitive flag as well. This will also not work for trailing empty query parameters. But still a very good answer based on OP's example and request.

Comment: Query parameters name can contain more than lowercase and uppercase letters. I would recommend using the negated character class `[^&=]` since AFAIK only those characters have any special meaning in this context.

Comment: Thank you... you are a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

I’d do it this way:

```
url.replace(/\?.*/, function(qs) {
  return qs.split('&').filter(function(parameterTuple) {
    return parameterTuple.split('=')[1];
  }).join('&');
});
```

Comment: url.replace does not store the value. You need to do url=url.replace(...)

Comment: Thank you for your response.. i'll try this method also